# How to assert (H4: [] = [] ++ []) in a coq problem when there is no typing information present?

Tags: regex, coq

I'm stuck in the following proof because I don't know how to 
    assert (H4: [] = [] ++ []).
in the last line below and, hence, apply MApp because there is no known type information in the context.
additionally, I can't apply app_nil_r from the previous exercises, or if I can I'm not sure how to do it - I was trying Apply (app_nil_r []). 
Any tips how to fix this?

Error: Cannot infer the implicit parameter X of nil whose type is "Type" in...

```
Fixpoint match_eps (re: @reg_exp ascii) : bool :=
  match re with
  | EmptySet => false
  | EmptyStr => true
  | Char _ => false
  | App r1 r2 => (match_eps r1) && (match_eps r2)
  | Union r1 r2 => (match_eps r1) || (match_eps r2)
  | Star r => match_eps r
  end.

Lemma match_eps_refl : refl_matches_eps match_eps.
Proof.
  unfold refl_matches_eps.
  intros.
  induction re.
  - simpl. apply ReflectF. unfold not. intros. inversion H.
  - simpl. apply ReflectT. apply MEmpty.
  - simpl. apply ReflectF. unfold not. intros.  inversion H.
  - simpl. inversion IHre1. inversion IHre2. 
    simpl. apply ReflectT.
    assert (H4: [] = [] ++ []).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `MApp` with explicit strings as arguments to avoid the ambiguity:

```
apply (MApp [] _ []).  (* Provided the goal is of the form   ([] ++ []) =~ App re0 re1   (i.e., the conclusion of the type of MApp) or   [] =~ App re0 re1  *)
                       (* (this should be fine because ([] ++ []) is definitionally equal to []) *)
```

---

Asserting `[] = [] ++ []` is problematic because the type of `[]` is ambiguous.  This assertion shouldn't be necessary here, but in general you can apply the `nil` constructor explicitly to pin down its type:

```
assert (@nil ascii = [] ++ []).  (* Note: [] is notation for "@nil _", leaving _ to be determined by type inference. All we're doing here is replacing "_" with something explicit. *)
```

Comment: Note that you can also write `[] = [] ++ [] :> list ascii`.

Comment: Oh, fancy. What does `:>` do exactly? (Can't find it in the manual)

Comment: https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/4a7a5c36802701d0e1b47956bb14cfc9cab99baa/theories/Init/Logic.v#L350-L353 : `"x = y :> A" := (@eq A x y) : type_scope.`

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd just use a more powerful tactic:

```
have H: [] ++ [] = [].
```

this will yield

```
H: forall T : Type, [::] ++ [::] = [::]
```

as `have` performs *generalization* of unbound types. This is very useful in practice.

`have` is in the `ssreflect` package, `From Coq Require Import ssreflect.`